# Play framework 2.4 different charset encoding in a view

Tags: java, playframework, character-encoding, playframework-2.0

I have a play framework application which gets string data from an external database and renders it in a view, but when I run the server on different system I have different outputs.

On Mac Sierra everything works fine, on Windows 10 accent letters are displayed with different chars and on ubuntu accent letters are displayed with �.

This happens only when text is retrieved from DB, instead if text is already present into html file everything works fine.